# I create class about toolbar and I can't use it in several activity

Tags: android, android-studio

```
public class ToolBarNavigation extends AppCompatActivity {

  public void exe (int address){

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(address);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_navigation, null);

    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    view.setLayoutParams(lp);

    relativeLayout.addView(view);
  }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ToolBarNavigation t1 = new ToolBarNavigation();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1.exe(R.id.relativeLayout1);
  }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m01nyabesh.yabesh/com.m01nyabesh.yabesh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
   at com.m01nyabesh.yabesh.ToolBarNavigation.exe(ToolBarNavigation.java:16)
   at com.m01nyabesh.yabesh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
```

Comment: I don't think LayourParams are added to ViewGroups not to layouts

Comment: Thank you , but what do you recommend way

Comment: `new ToolBarNavigation();` - never ever, ever, make a new Activity class like that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use default toolbar in Different activity do following (Source code taken from previous project and I using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) && Android SupportDesign):

First create `BaseActivity.java` Class like:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //rest of common initialization may goes here
    }

    protected void setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Then define your own activity and extend from `BaseActivity.java` something like:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        setupToolbar();

    }

    @Override
    protected void setupToolbar() {
        super.setupToolbar();
        setTitle(R.string.title_activity);
    }
}
```

In your activity.xml include your default Toolbar like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/default_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar_default" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

     <!-- other ui element goes here -->


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is your `include_toolbar_default.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Might want to mention you need Butterknife to use this code

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are creating the toolbar before the activity is created,

try to create the toolbar inside OnCreate function, and you dont show if the layout activity_main, cointains a toolbar, you should get the reference of the layout and then inflate that view with your custom code

Comment: Thanks your response, but when I copy this code in MainActivity, it's true and I see good result